# Transitive nature in concept of inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

**Question:**

In the concept of inheritance in java I read about various advantages of using inheritance in java where I came across a advantage known as transitive nature.
Now I looked upon google to find the meaning of transitive where I got the meaning as “ it is a relation such that it applies between successive members of a sequence ,it must also apply between any two members taken in order.For instance ,if A is larger than B ,and B is larger than C,then A is larger than C”.
I understand the meaning but cannot get a direct link between the the word transitive and the concept of inheritance.

*Is there any explanation ,to understand this in a more clear cut way?*

Comment: There we two meanings provided ,one for grammar and one for logic and mathematics,I have provided the logic and mathematics meaning.If I am somehow wrong ,please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Porche IS-A Car, and a Car IS-A Automobile then a Porche IS-A Automobile.

EDIT - as requested, here is some code to demonstrate this.

```
public class Automobile
{
    private int fuel = 0;
    public void giveFuel(int amount)
    {
        fuel += amount;
    }
}
public class Car extends Automobile
{
}
public class Porche extends Car
{
}
```

So now I can obviously do:
`Automobile auto = new Automobile();`

`auto.giveFuel(5);`
But I can even do:
`Porche porche = new Porche();`

`porche.giveFuel(5);`
And if a function expects an Automobile:

```
public class Person
{
    private Automobile ride = 0;
    public void setRide(Automobile ride)
    {
        this.ride = ride;
    }
}
```

I can do:
`Porche porche = new Porche();`
`Person person = new Person()`
`person.setRide(porche);`
This is especially useful if the subclasses override function of the superclass that will make them act a bit differently. So maybe each Car subclass has a different `drive()` method that takes a different amount of fuel (Car itself could be abstract) and when the Person wants to use their car, he will call `ride.drive()` and the correct amount of fuel will be taken.

Comment: Does inheritance actually mean this?I have written some small programs in java using the concept of inheritance where I notice reusability advantage clearly but never the example of the transitive nature that you have provided.Can you write a small snippet showing the transitive nature?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll often see inheritance being described as a is-a relationship.

For example, let's take the vehicle example, now it's an abstract term, it could mean several things, so in our code it makes sense to make `vehicle` an `abstract` `class`.

```
public abstract class Vehicle {
     private String name;
     private int gasAmount;

     //constructors, getters etc...

     public abstract void start();
     public abstract void drive();
     // other methods
}

public class Truck extends Vehicle
{    
   public Truck(string name, int gas){
         :super(name,gas)
   }

   @Override
   public void drive(){}

   @Override
   public void start(){}

}
```

A truck is a vehicle and so it becomes aware of the methods that are in `Vehicle` and can override them. If `gasAmount` and `name` were `protected` then the sub classes, in this case `Truck`, would be able to see and access them.

Let's take it a step further, `Truck`, while a little more specific, could be describing several trucks, for example, a dump truck, so:

`public class DumpTruck extends Truck`